# Running multiple Debezium connectors on the same source MariaDB

Tags: apache-kafka, mariadb, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

We have multiple MariaDB schemas and for each of those running two debezium connectors. Everything runs fine for a while but then every 1-2 weeks or so debezium error on random connector occurs:

```
2022-10-31 06:18:55,106 ERROR  MySQL|scheme_1|binlog  Error during binlog processing. Last offset stored = {transaction_id=null, ts_sec=1667155787, file=mysql-bin.075628, pos=104509320, server_id=1, event=32}, binlog reader near position = mysql-bin.075628/300573885   [io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource]
2022-10-31 06:18:55,107 ERROR  MySQL|scheme_1|binlog  Producer failure   [io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler]
io.debezium.DebeziumException: Connection reset
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.wrap(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:1189)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource$ReaderThreadLifecycleListener.onCommunicationFailure(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:1234)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:980)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:599)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$7.run(BinaryLogClient.java:857)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.io.BufferedSocketInputStream.read(BufferedSocketInputStream.java:59)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.io.ByteArrayInputStream.readWithinBlockBoundaries(ByteArrayInputStream.java:261)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.io.ByteArrayInputStream.read(ByteArrayInputStream.java:245)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.io.ByteArrayInputStream.fill(ByteArrayInputStream.java:112)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.io.ByteArrayInputStream.read(ByteArrayInputStream.java:105)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.readPacketSplitInChunks(BinaryLogClient.java:995)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:953)
        ... 3 more
2022-10-31 06:18:55,113 INFO   MySQL|scheme_1|binlog  Stopped reading binlog after 0 events, last recorded offset: {transaction_id=null, ts_sec=1667155787, file=mysql-bin.075628, pos=104509320, server_id=1, event=32}   [io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource]
2022-10-31 06:18:55,123 ERROR  ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=scheme_1-connector-1666100046785939106-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.
        at io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler.setProducerThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:50)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource$ReaderThreadLifecycleListener.onCommunicationFailure(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:1234)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:980)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:599)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$7.run(BinaryLogClient.java:857)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: io.debezium.DebeziumException: Connection reset
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.wrap(MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource.java:1189)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.io.BufferedSocketInputStream.read(BufferedSocketInputStream.java:59)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.io.ByteArrayInputStream.readWithinBlockBoundaries(ByteArrayInputStream.java:261)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.io.ByteArrayInputStream.read(ByteArrayInputStream.java:245)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.io.ByteArrayInputStream.fill(ByteArrayInputStream.java:112)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.io.ByteArrayInputStream.read(ByteArrayInputStream.java:105)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.readPacketSplitInChunks(BinaryLogClient.java:995)
        at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:953)
        ... 3 more
2022-10-31 06:18:55,132 INFO   ||  Stopping down connector   [io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask]
```

This must be related to fact that we have two connectors attached, because there are no problems if there's one connector per schema.
MariaDB server didn't go down because we have another connector on the same server and it wasn't affected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that two independent connectors would crash at exactly the same binlog position because of each others presence.

```
ts_sec=1667155787, file=mysql-bin.075628, pos=104509320, server_id=1, event=32
```

Take the `mariadb-binlog --start-position=104509320 mysql-bin.075628` from that position (just one full entry is probably sufficient) and [raise a bug report](https://issues.redhat.com/projects/DBZ/issues) (if one doesn't already exist).